# Is $E[\frac{\alpha}{b+x}]$ decreasing in $\alpha$ when $x$ is Gamma distributed with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

My question is whether $E[\frac{\alpha}{b+x}]$ is decreasing in $\alpha$ when $x$ is Gamma distributed with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (under the shape/rate parameterization).

It seems like it would hold intuitively, and numerically, but the actual derivative of the expectation is incredibly complicated, so I don't even know where to start.

Comment: are you sure this claim holds for all $\alpha$?

Comment: brief attempt: I get something like 
$$ {\alpha\beta^\alpha \over \Gamma(\alpha) } \int_{\beta}^{+\infty} { (z-\beta)^{\alpha-1} \over z }\exp(-(z-\beta)\beta)dz $$
I think the integral is bounded for large $\alpha$ and you'd then be left with checking that the factor at the front decreases in $\alpha$ for large $\alpha$